# In visual studio code, How can I hide file path below file tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, breadcrumbs

I wanted to move it to up of file tabs on VScode.
Cannot find the option to hide the original path.

If it is not possible, moving it to the top of file tabs is also valid.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This thing is called "breadcrumbs".

Disable it by unchecking `Breadcrumbs: Enabled` in the settings. (Or add `"breadcrumbs.enabled": false` to your `settings.json`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: this help me also, short way >> from View menu remove check on  `show breadcrumbs`